# First level parent navigation show on sidebar even in child pages i visit?

Tags: 2013, navigation

How can I get the code to show the first level parent page name in it's child's in sidebar navigation.

Let's say I have a parent page "About Us" and under it I have overview, mission, philosophy etc. I want to get the Parent Page "About Us" code snippet in all sub pages to print in a particular place instead of in the sidebar to show user in which parent category user is?